# jQuery list that saves user selection (like a cart)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, shopping-cart

I'm working on a travel website. I'm looking for a function that allows my users to click a hotel and save their selection to a "list" on the sidebar.

I want it to function like a cart so that the list never erases and so that you can see the selection until you are ready to print everything out.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your users are going to be clicking around to a lot of pages, it will be a real challenge to keep sending this growing list around from page to page on the client side. I would recommend that you consider a different approach. One is cookies, and another is session state.

If you are using server-side code, it would help us to know what language you are using so that we can give you some more ideas.

Comment: I'm using Javascript and PHP inside of Wordpress.

Comment: OK, I changed your tags to help you get attention to your question from the right people.

Comment: Haha. Thanks so much. Really appreciate you assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting using AJAX to pass the selection to the backend.  If you want this to persist across multiple sessions you're going to want to save it to a database so they can come back later.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks kingjiv. I'm going through the list now to try and pick out what I may need to make this thing work. Preciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies if you don't want to use php.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
has a good example of how to use cookies in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using "[My favourite posts](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/wordpress-plugin-my-favorite-posts)" wordpress plugin for this kind of job.